# Pandas Rows with missing values in multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `age`, `date` and `location`.

1. I would like to count how many rows are empty across ALL columns (not some but all in the same time). I have the following code, each line works independently, but how do I say `age AND date AND location` isnull?

   ```
   df['age'].isnull().sum()
   df['date'].isnull().sum()
   df['location'].isnull().sum()
   ```
2. I would like to return a dataframe after removing the rows with missing values in ALL these three columns, so something like the following lines but combined in one statement:

   ```
   df.mask(row['location'].isnull())
   df[np.isfinite(df['age'])]
   df[np.isfinite(df['date'])]
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can use your approach, but drop the column indices:

```
df.isnull().sum().sum()
```

The first `.sum()` returns a per-column value, while the second `.sum()` will return the sum of all `NaN` values.

Similar to [Vaishali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746169/4791226), you can use `df.dropna()` to drop all values that are `NaN` or `None` and only return your cleaned DataFrame.

```
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [1, 2, 3, np.NaN, 4, None], 'date': [1, 2, 3, 4, None, 5], 'location': ['a', 'b', 'c', None, 'e', 'f']})

In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
   age  date location
0  1.0   1.0        a
1  2.0   2.0        b
2  3.0   3.0        c
3  NaN   4.0     None
4  4.0   NaN        e
5  NaN   5.0        f

In [47]: df.isnull().sum().sum()
Out[47]: 4

In [48]: df.dropna()
Out[48]: 
   age  date location
0  1.0   1.0        a
1  2.0   2.0        b
2  3.0   3.0        c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the no of rows with all NaNs by

```
len(df) - len(df.dropna(how = 'all'))
```

and drop by

```
df = df.dropna(how = 'all')
```

This will drop the rows with all the NaN values